# Getting data as array instead of stdClass in zf-rest

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I'm using zf-rest for building my RESTful web apps. I have the following configurations:

```
'zf-rest' => [
  Resource\FeedbackResource::class => [
    'listener' => Resource\FeedbackResource::class,
    'route_name' => 'api/rest/feedback',
    'entity_http_methods' => [
    ],
    'collection_http_methods' => [
      'POST',
    ],
  ],
],
'zf-content-validation' => [
  Resource\FeedbackResource::class => [
    'use_raw_data' => false,
    'allows_only_fields_in_filter' => true,
    'POST' => Resource\FeedbackResource::class . '\\Validator',
  ],
],
'input_filter_specs' => [
  Resource\FeedbackResource::class . '\\Validator' => [
    Resource\FeedbackResource::PARAM_NAME => $inputFilterSpecForStrings,
    Resource\FeedbackResource::PARAM_EMAIL => $inputFilterSpecForStrings,
  ],
],
```

Then I created the resource with the corresponding method:

```
class FeedbackResource extends AbstractResourceListener
{
  public function create($data)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I posted a json string to the endpoint and everything works fine so far. But what I'm wondering about is that I will get $data as an object with the json data as attributes. I expected to get an assoziative array. Is this possible?